# How to parse a substring like "CM-220" from a string using sed in a bash script

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a string:

```
blah\n blah\n blah Refs: CM-220
```

I know I can extract CM-220 using sed like below

```bash
echo 'blah\n blah\n blah Refs: CM-220' | sed 's/.*Refs: \([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

But I want to make it more strictly to extract it as **alphabet** + "-" + **number**.

Comment: If the string is a shell variable, I'd use bash's built in regular expressions instead, fwiw.

Comment: `echo 'blah\n blah\n blah Refs: CM-220' | sed 's/.*Refs: \([[:alpha:]]\{2\}\).*\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)/\1 \2/'`

Comment: @Shawn thanks for your answer! Can you give me an example?

Comment: When I'm at a computer and not my phone, sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `sed` with `ERE` mode i.e. `-E` option:

```sh
echo 'blah\n blah\n blah Refs: CM-220' |
sed -E 's/.*Refs: ([[:alpha:]]+-[[:digit:]]+).*/\1/'

CM-220
```

`[[:alpha:]]+-[[:digit:]]+` is translation of your required pattern: `alphabet + "-" + number` where `[[:alpha:]]+` matches 1 or more alphabetic characters and `[[:digit:]]+` matches 1 or more digits.

Answer (score 2):

If the string you're matching is stored in a shell variable, you can do it using `bash`'s built-in regular expressions instead of having to execute `sed` or another external program:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

str="blah
 blah
 blah Refs: CM-220"
re="Refs: ([[:alpha:]]+-[[:digit:]]+)"

if [[ $str =~ $re ]]; then
    printf "Found: %s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tested it and found BASH_REMATCH[1] is CM-220, BASH_REMATCH[0] is "Refs: CM-220". Is it a rule for bash's built-in regular expressions? So we use BASH_REMATCH[1]  to get exactly what we want.

Comment: @echo The first element of the array is the complete text of the match, and the rest are the first, second, etc. capture group.